# how to solve geopandas package installing problem

Tags: pandas

While I am trying to install the geopandas package, I got this error.
Could you please help in this regard.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VJRl.png)

Comment: What's the error? Can you post it? The image you added does not show it

Comment: click on the details and add it to your question, please